# Importance sampling for bernoulli-sequence, favouring long sequences of ones

Tags: probability-distributions, sequences-and-series, simulation, binomial-distribution

Assume we have a sequence of i.i.d. bernoulli-distributed random variables of length $n$.

I'm interested in doing rare event simulation and my event depends, among other random factors, on the occurence of (at least) one subsequence of ones in the bernoulli sequence, the length which has to be around $Cn^{1-\xi}$ with known constants $C$ and $\xi$, which is (of course) in $(0,1)$.

I spent some time looking for examples of this, but failed to find something so far. I'm considering some ideas, though they seem somewhat messy and hard to work on, so I hope I missed something or looked for the wrong key words. Does anyone has read something about this problem or have experience with this?

Comment: Is there something wrong with randomly choosing a section of the string of the appropriate length, making it all ones, and then picking the rest of the bits randomly?

Comment: @Noah Stein Yes. Consider 3 coin tosses conditioned on at least 2 heads in a row. We have HHH, HHT, THH with probability 1/3 each. On the other head, first choosing HH? or ?HH with probability 1/2 each and then deciding the value of ? at random (fifty-fifty chance) results in HHH having probability 1/2. There should be some easy way to compensate for this effect though.